# Convert string, so each letter of sentence is uppercase in SQL

Tags: sql, string, case

Using SQL I am looking to UPDATE data already present in a table.

The data column is set to string

example:

"hello. i am using stackoverflow."

I would like for it to change to

"Hello. I am using stackoverflow."

The desire here is for the first letter of each sentence to be uppercase, so not strictly Sentence Case?

I've tried a few things, but have only achieved first letter of string so far?

My guess would be that I need to find a substring character of . and take a 2 character substring after that to capitalize, im not to sure if this is even possible with SQL.

Comment: Ok. Good luck with that. Did you have a programming question? This site is for questions, not a place to dump your to-do list

Comment: MySQL, of all major RDBMS, is the worst suited to do such a string manipulation, which would probably require a regex, and _any_ database is not really the place to do this.  Rather, you should clean up the string _before_ it even hits the database.

Comment: @MarcB I feel this is a fair question, as there is not a lot of information in the world that could help with this.

Comment: @matthewr, the issue here is that programming languages are built with its purpose. I don't think such a manipulation can be easily accomplished with SQL, I support Tim's point.

Comment: @matthewr: 'question' - do you see a `?` in there? It's a to-do list, and we're not here to do OP's job for them.

Comment: @MarcB please be constructive and not critical, advise on approaching the task would have been appreciated.

Comment: "did you have a question?" can't get any more blatant. This site is for programming problems. Programmers, of all people, should be well aware of the need for pedanticism.

Comment: @MarcB Do you feel my task is feasible? I have a problem, I am unsure if SQL is sufficient for dealing with my task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using this function

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[InitialCap](@String VARCHAR(8000))
                  RETURNS VARCHAR(8000)
                 AS
 BEGIN 

                   DECLARE @Position INT;

SELECT @String   = STUFF(LOWER(@String),1,1,UPPER(LEFT(@String,1))) COLLATE Latin1_General_Bin,
                    @Position = PATINDEX('%[^A-Za-z''][a-z]%',@String COLLATE Latin1_General_Bin);

                    WHILE @Position > 0
                    SELECT @String   = STUFF(@String,@Position,2,UPPER(SUBSTRING(@String,@Position,2))) COLLATE Latin1_General_Bin,
                    @Position = PATINDEX('%[^A-Za-z''][a-z]%',@String COLLATE Latin1_General_Bin);

                     RETURN @String;
  END ;
```

Comment: and if OP isn't on mssql?

Comment: sorry I didn't get u what do u mean by OP

Comment: op = original poster, e.g. the person who asked the question.

Comment: I never tried it with other relational databases , bu u can use the sme regiular expression

Comment: Thanks @AMH I feel I can chop pieces of that and make it fit

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
declare @str varchar(max)  = 'i am. i am. this is a string';

declare @ld int = 1, @i int = 1
declare @c varchar(1)
declare @str2 varchar(max) = ''

while @i <= len(@str)
begin

    select  @c = substring (@str, @i, 1)

    if @ld = 1 and @c != ' '
    begin
        select  @ld = 0
        select  @c = upper(@c)
    end

    select  @str2 = @str2 + @c
    if @c = '.'
        select @ld = 1

    select  @i = @i + 1
end

select  @str2
```